# How to get an array of data from a php API ( laravel lumen) in Angular

Tags: php, angular, lumen, angular-httpclient

I'm stuck as it is my first time using Angular and I might have not understood some basics.

I've made a PHP API that returns data from a MySQL database, and I get them in angular using HttpClient.

The call to the database is:

```
public function showOneCoursBy($id){
    $results = DB::select("select * from cours where id_cours = ".$id);
    return $results;
}
```

Accessing the API page I get:

> [{"id_cours":1,"id_exercice":1,"titre":"XXX","description":"XXX","contenu":"XXX","mediaPath":"XXX","dateDebut":"0000-00-00","dateFin":"0000-00-00"}]

So it seems right.

In Angular, I get the data with

```
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private http: HttpClient,
    public db: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/cours/').
    toPromise().then(data => {
      console.log(Object.keys(data).map(key => ({type: key, value: data[key]})));
      }
    );
  }
```

In a service,
the `console.log` do return

```
(2) […]​
0: {…}​​
type: "0"​​
value: Object { id_cours: 1, id_exercice: 1, titre: "Premier Cours", … }
<prototype>: Object { … }
1: {…}​
type: "1"​
value: Object { id_cours: 2, id_exercice: 2, titre: "Cours n°2", … }
<prototype>: Object { … }
length: 2​
<prototype>: [
```

But how can I get only one of those element as an array? Or access only one property?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `Object.keys(data).map(key => ({type: key, value: data[key]}))[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply declare an interface for the Object

```
export interface Exercice { 
  id_cours: number;
  id_exercice: number;
  titre: string;
  description: string;
  contenu: string;
  mediaPath: string;
  dateDebut: string;
  dateFin: string
}
```

You access the data by typing your response as Exercice

```
 this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/cours/')
   .pipe(take(1))
   .subscrible((response: Exercice[]) => {
     response.forEach(exercice => console.log(exercice.titre));
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response =)
that seems to work, but I can't get it to display it, as doing things like 
``` this.allExercice = response ``` 
get me a "this.allExercice is undefineded"
Or
```
response.forEach(exercice => this.allExercice.push(exercice));
```
get me the same error...

Returning the resposne give me a "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Exercice[]'."

Comment: How did you declare allExercice array ? Did you initialized it ? by declaring for example : private allExercice: Exercice[] = [];